# Get a check box with its value having special characters

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am having trouble in dynamically checking a check box (finding by its value) which have special characters in its value.

i am trying this

```
$('#store_cat').find("[value="abc"]").prop('checked', true);
```

but when i have value like `abc_&_def` it fails.

Need help
Regards

Comment: is "store_cat" the checkbox?

Comment: no "store_cat" is a "li" where all the check boxes are

Comment: good, just wanted to check, I would also make sure to be careful with single and double quotes

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/npp7pjnn/1/

Comment: Thanks guys. it was a typo thanks for pointing . i cant accept all answers but arun was first to answer. so arun can u plz post this in answer so that i can accept.

Comment: @Atranaz if it was a typo... then it is better to delete the question

Comment: @ArunPJohny i tired but they said sorry :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#store_cat').find('[value="abc"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Or if the value is likely to change during the life of the page:

```
$('#store_cat :checkbox').filter(function() {
    return this.value.trim() = "abc";
}).prop('checked', true);
```

**PLEASE NOTE**: The value attribute gives you the initial value of a form control, which value does not change unless the value of the attribute is explicitly changed; `val( new_value )` does not change the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function

```
function chkVal(chkvalue){
    var chkboxval = chkvalue;
    var $this = $('#store_cat input:checkbox');
    if($this.val()==chkboxval){
        $this.prop("checked", true );
    }
}
```

Then call the function with the value you're looking for like this:

```
chkVal('abc_&_def');
chkVal('abc');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()`

```js
$('#store_cat :checkbox').filter(function() {
  return this.value == "abc_&_abc";
}).prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="store_cat">
  <input type="checkbox" value="a" />a
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="abc_&_abc" />abc_&_abc
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="a" />a
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="a" />a
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="abc_&_abc" />abc_&_abc
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="abc_&_abc" />abc_&_abc
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="a" />a
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="a" />a
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="abc_&_abc" />abc_&_abc
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="abc_&_abc" />abc_&_abc
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="a" />a
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="a" />a
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="abc_&_abc" />abc_&_abc
  <br>
</div>
```